# How to make "conda" download packages in parallel

Tags: anaconda, conda, miniconda

`conda install -y <package_name>` will install the package and its dependencies. This is done in one-by-one fashion.

Can it be done in parallel ? Just only the downloading part ?

[image]

Comment: Having same issue. ANyone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 2021 the correct answer is to [use mamba](https://github.com/mamba-org/mamba). It's a very fast reimplementation of conda in C++ supporting parallel downloading/extracting.

Comment: Not exactly what I'm asking for, but since conda doesn't support this, this may be the best option.

Comment: mamba still delegates the installation to conda so the correct answer would be to use micromamba which does not depend on conda at all.

Answer (score 1):

Afaik, `conda` doesn't provide that option.

If you know in advance which packages will be installed, it is possible to download them beforehand into `$CONDA_HOME/pkgs/` and add their URLs to `$CONDA_HOME/pkgs/urls.txt`. Then `conda` will use them without downloading again.

On Linux, you could use `xargs -P -n` on `curl` to implement parallel downloads.

Answer (score 0):

It seems conda on Linux parallel automatically. In Windows, it download in a serial manner.

Answer (score -1):

[Here's](https://github.com/milesgranger/parallel-conda) a package that enables parallel installation.